# apps download error

Tags: applications, downloading

Whenever I try to download apps I receive error "error while Dowunloading-application name" there is insufficient space on the device.

Please help me to overcome this and I have sufficient space on device and SD Card. Sony Xperia C2305. Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because application download from the store first heads over to the internal storage of the device which I guess isn't enough, what you can do is try moving some of the application installed/music/pictures over to the SD card in order to free up the internal storage. You can also try clearing the Dumpstate/logcat to try freeing up some space you can do that by pressing *#9900# and select the second option "Delete DumpState/logcat" and see if this helps you in freeing up some space.